# trim numerical and separator values from the beginning of strings in swift

Tags: string, swift

From:

```
let fruit = ["012Red Apple", "03218Yellow Banana", "11 Orange Orange"]
```

I would like to get:

```
var result = ["Red Apple", "Yellow Banana", "Orange Orange"]
```

What is the best way to do this in the latest Swift?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this

```
var fruitAlpha: [String] = []
for f in fruit {
    fruitAlpha.append(f.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet().invertedSet))
}
```

As Leo noted, it's better to use just letter set and just invert it. This will work for all non letter characters.

Comment: this would trim it also from the end of the string

Comment: It doesn't trim the end of the string. Why would it?

Comment: Oh that, well yes. This is what was asked in the question.

Comment: There is also the space char, which needs to be trimmed.

Comment: @t1. you can use letterCharacterSet invertedSet

Comment: Yes, I realized, this would do: 

stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "0123456789 \t"))

Comment: @LeoDabus totally missed that there were spaces in the requirements as well. In that case, inverted set is probably the best idea.

Comment: Trim is still not the best solution, it cuts off the end also, which is not acceptable here.

Comment: @t1. you haven't specified that you want suffix digits.

Comment: I edited the examples to make this clear. The emphasis is on the "beginning of the string" as originally stated.

Comment: If your string can ever end in digits then `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` is not a good choice. It trims away characters in the specified set from the beginning AND end of the string, until the first occurrence of a character not in the specified set. So "012Red Apple8675309" would get trimmed to "Red Apple".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression like this:

```
let fruits = ["012Apple", "03218Banana", "11 Orange"]
var results = [String]()

for fruit in fruits {

    if let match = fruit.rangeOfString("[a-zA-Z]+", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {

        results.append(fruit.substringWithRange(match))
    }
}
print(results) // Apple, Banana, Orange
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a regex of find the range of digits, spaces, etc.. at the beginning of your strings and use removeRange() method:

```
var fruits = ["012Red Apple", "03218Yellow Banana", "11 Orange Orange"]

for (index,fruit) in fruits.enumerate() {
    if let range = fruit.rangeOfString("[\\d )-]*\\s*", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
        fruits[index].removeRange(range)
    }
}

print(fruits) // ["Red Apple", "Yellow Banana", "Orange Orange"]\n"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex, i think it'll fit what you want:

```
let fruits = ["012Apple red", "03218Banana cool", "11 Orange black 133"]
var results = [String]()

for fruit in fruits {

    if let match = fruit.rangeOfString("[a-zA-Z ]+", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {

        results.append(fruit.substringWithRange(match))
    }
}
print(results) // Apple red, Banana cool, Orange black
```